# Shell has become very slow since upgrading OSX

Tags: shell, zsh, osx-mavericks

I have recently upgraded to OSX Mavericks and since then my console has become very slow and unresponsive.

I am using the oh-my-zsh ZSH shell

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming-related questions; please try at http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Olive, please don't be put off. Stack Overflow is quite strict about what's allowed on each site, otherwise we end up with a big mess. Post again on apple.stackexchange.com and you'll get a better result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sammynammari posted a fix for a similar problem [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2189) on github. It is caused by the vi-mode plugin so you must disable it until it has been fixed.

Open up your .zshrc file and remove the vi-mode plugin from the plugins list.

**Before:**

```
plugins=(vi-mode)
```

**After:**

```
plugins=()
```

Once you restart the console it should be fine again. If it doesn't work then try disabling all the plugins, then if that works gradually re-enable them one by one to find the culprit.